# Change default value from storyboard in code

Tags: swift

Need change this value:

[image]

I want to change in View(not rootView in NavigationController)

```
modalPresentationStyle = .popover
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what do You mean change in View. But if You need to change it in ViewController You can override prepare method:

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    segue.destination.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
}
```

Comment: I have hierarchy: VC1 -> NavVC -- VC2 -> VC3 -> VC4; If i override in VC1 -> my views will be .popover. I want to change VC2.modalPresentation = .formSheet, VC3.modalPresentation = .fullScreen but override in specific views doesnt work...

Comment: Could You prepare any repository with this example?